# Why do end device need to support VLANS?

Tags: networking, printer, vlan

I am reading https://kb.netgear.com/000048453/What-do-I-need-to-know-about-setting-up-VLANs and it mentions

`Most printers do not recognize 802.1Q tags.`

This statement confuses me because I thought the tagging/untagging happen on the L3 switch access port? Why do I care if printer recognize the tag or not? As far as i concern printer connecting to L3 switch port will always receive untagged packet right?

What senario are they possible referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect devices to an 'access' (untagged-only) port, then yes, the devices themselves don't need to care about VLANs at all.

The note is mainly about connecting these devices to 'trunk' or 'hybrid' ports, which *intentionally* have multiple tagged VLANs facing the device.

For example, this especially applies when such a port is further split up using an *unmanaged* (VLAN-incapable) switch – e.g. if there's only a single Ethernet port going into an office, into that other switch, and then into PCs and printers and IP phones and so on. In such a situation, the admin might try to separate certain devices by making them tag their own traffic.

(One might use hybrid ports for Wi-Fi access points, which often support hosting multiple networks and using different VLAN tags for each. In fact some places even assign VLANs dynamically for different users.)

Comment: With a better Wi-Fi access point, I can have different SSID map to different VLAN right? In this way I am essentially creating multiple access port with different SSID

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you may want an end device to be on more than one VLAN, so you make its switch port a trunk port and put multiple tagged VLANs on it, and configure the end device to have a virtual interface on each VLAN.

Suppose you had a fancy printer and you wanted it to be discoverable on every VLAN in the office building, but you have a diverse mix of client OSes so you can’t just say “well, all the Windows PCs will find it through Active Directory”. So you want it to actually be on all office VLANs so that all the different native service discovery schemes work.

Comment: I see, this is a very good use case thank you! Slightly off-topic, if I can really configure my NIC to be any VLAN ID, can't I somehow invade other people VLAN? Assuming im connected to trunk port. This seems like a security issue

Comment: @Zanko. Yes, you must be careful not to give people access to trunk ports, or make sure their trunk port isn’t assigned any VLANs that they shouldn’t have access to.